Oauth verification process home page and privacy policy link problem

I have set up separate URLs for my OAuth consent screen:
Homepage: https://moneylite.in
Privacy Policy: https://moneylite.in/privacy-policy
Additionally, I have added a link to the privacy policy in the footer of the homepage.
Despite this, I'm still receiving the following issues from Google's Trust and Safety team:
"Your home page does not include a link to your privacy policy."
"Your privacy policy URL is the same as your home page URL."
I have already verified and authorized my domain, so I'm unsure why these issues persist. Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have suggestions on how to resolve this?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

email them back and tell them you don't understand the issue.  From what i can see your home page has a link at the bottom to the privacy policy page.    Or double check that you have added the correct links.
